# Distance between two affine lines using determinant of Gramian matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

I've a task to find the distance in $E^4$ between:

$L = [1,2,-1,4] + \text{lin}((1,2,-1,0))$

and

$M = [2,3,1,5] + \text{lin}((2,1,0,2))$

My efforts to find the correct solution:

Let

$\alpha_{1}=(1,2,-1,0)
 , \alpha_{2}=(2,1,0,2)$

$p_{0}=[2,3,1,5]$

$p\in R^{4}
  p\in L$

$p=(1+t,2+2t,-1-t,4)$

$\overrightarrow{p_{0}p}=(t-1,2t-1,2t,-1)$

$f(t)=
 d(p,M)$

Then (W is a determinant of grammian matrix)

$f(t)=\sqrt{\frac{W(\alpha_{2},\overrightarrow{p_{0}p})}{W(\alpha_{2})}}$

$<\alpha_{2},\alpha_{2}>=3$

$W(\alpha_{2})=3$

$W(\alpha_{2},\overrightarrow{p_{0}p})=\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}
<\alpha_{2},\alpha_{2}> & <\alpha_{2},\overrightarrow{p_{0}p}>\\
<\overrightarrow{p_{0}p},\alpha_{2}> & <\overrightarrow{p_{0}p},\overrightarrow{p_{0}p}>
\end{array}\right)$

$<\overrightarrow{p_{0}p},\overrightarrow{p_{0}p}>=\sqrt{(t-1)^{2}+(2t-1)^{2}+4t^{2}+1}=\sqrt{t^{2}-2t+1-4t^{2}+1+4t^{2}+1}=\sqrt{t^{2}-2t+1}=\sqrt{(t-1)^{2}}=t-1$

$<\alpha_{2},\overrightarrow{p_{0}p}>=<\overrightarrow{p_{0}p},\alpha_{2}>=\sqrt{2t-2+2t-1-2}=\sqrt{4t-5}$

$W(\alpha_{2},\overrightarrow{p_{0}p})=\det\left(\begin{array}{cc}
3 & \sqrt{4t-5}\\
\sqrt{4t-5} & \mid t-1\mid
\end{array}\right)=\\3\cdot\mid t-1\mid-\mid4t-5\mid=\begin{cases}
-3t+3+4t-5 & \iff t<1\\
3t-3+4t-5 & \iff t\in[1,\frac{5}{4})\\
3t-3-4t+5 & \iff t>\frac{5}{4}
\end{cases}=\begin{cases}
t-2 & \iff t<1\\
7t-8 & \iff t\in[1,\frac{5}{4})\\
-t+2 & \iff t\geq\frac{5}{4}
\end{cases}$

From that I noticed, that distance can be negative, and I don't know how to fix it

Could you help me to point, where I made an error in reasoning?

Thanks in advance for all advices!

Comment: First, your square roots are incorrect. Second, you've computed $\|\overrightarrow{p_0p}\|^2$ incorrectly. I would not have thought to use the Gram determinant; can you explain what you would do with the correct value of $W(t)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, I'll fix it and check if it;s working. I'm using the formula to compute distance between point and affine subspace, which use Gram determinant.